# Pylab Histogram show all bins on x axis

Tags: python, graph, histogram, matplotlib

Im writing a small python program to do a frequency analysis, and I was wondering how you might get all the bins to show on the x axis rather then just in increments of 5. Also is there a way you can display a string value like "A" on the x axis instead of a number?

Code:

```
print "Please specify the file to analyse."
FileContents = FileToIntArray()

# Count letter occurances in file
letterCounts = zeros(26).tolist()
for x in FileContents:
    i = AlphaNum.index(x)
    letterCounts[i] = letterCounts[i] + 1

# Plot histogram of counts
print "" # Newline
title("Absolute Frequencies")
xlabel("Letters A-B (Where A = 0 & Z = 25)")
ylabel("Letter Occurences")
hist(letterCounts, bins=AlphaNum)
show()
```

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: When you say all bins to show do you mean all of the tick labels?

Comment: Yeah, just the values I want along the x axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [xticks](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks).

```
xticks(arange(len(AlphaNum)),AlphaNum)
```